# Openshift: After modifying code and Git push. Changes dont show

Tags: git, deployment, tomcat7, openshift

I created a new app in `OpenShift`. App got created successfully and cloned to the local directory also. I modified and changed the default `index.html` all also add  `web.xml` to put `index.html` in `welcome-file-list`. But it doesn't show the changes at all. when I run the URL, it would show the default index.html.
even appending the `index.html` URL, it still shows the default page

> I deleted the app multiple times and created a new one with a new local repo in order to check what is going wrong
>
> Every time I do SSH on the app, the current folder, would sometimes show the changes updated while sometimes, it doesnt show.

I used the basic process to create app, given in the tutorials:

- `rhc app-create <appname> tomcat7`

After creating the app, I modified index.html and `git add --all`, `git commit -m`,  `git push`

The output was success as shown here:

```
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

> I have spent almost half of the day looking around on web for same issue. It has never happened before. I already had an application deployed and I would push updates to the App and they would reflect smoothly.

Please help me to resolve it.thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a solution to it.

Once we create the app in rhcloud, It will create the pom.xml which would have many default values with it. so the bottom line is:

> Do not **replace** the `pom.xml` with the one which you have kept **offline
>   for your project**. **Modify** the pom.xml already created in rhcloud webapp
>   and incase you want to change the compiler version and dependencies,
>   do it their on the xml file which is created by-default. **Dont
>   completely replace it.**

It worked for me. Hope works for any one who had this issue.

Comment: dude you are great! I have this same problem, after that I tried not replace the whole pom.xml and add those dependency one by one and it worked. I think the key is the last tag "profile", it has to be set as openshift. Anyway, i think it should inform users to avoid replace it since a lot of users they just want to upload their existing project

Comment: Hi. Can you explain how to do this. I am also facing the same problem. I have pom.xml excluded from commit. But still when i push the code, the cloud pom.xml is updated.

Comment: I am not sure, if i got your question properly.

Comment: I am not sure, if i got your question properly.
But here are the steps i followed:

1) once you create a new `openshift` project and clone it your local machine. It created a new maven project with its own `pom.xml` 
2) now if you have `pom.xml` file already created for your project.
3) i suggest you to compare your `pom.xml` with the generated one.
4) copy your changes in the generated `pom.xml`.
5) do the commit .

_note: if you try to put your own `pom.xml`, it will not update it due to some dependency conflict._