# Updating pom.xml in OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I have developed an OpenShift application locally on NetBeans and have pushed the code to server including pom.xml changes. Now my changes are not reflecting. I understand from [Openshift: After modifying code and Git push. Changes dont show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599959/openshift-after-modifying-code-and-git-push-changes-dont-show) that pom changes should be made manually rather than replacing the entire file. 
Is there a way to revert this?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to take a look at the `pom.xml` template that comes witht the *JBoss EWS* cartridge, you can find it [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/template/pom.xml).

If you want just to revert your changes to the `pom.xml` file in your repo, you can use git to do that (`git checkout <commit> path/to/pom.xml` then modify it as you need, add, commit and push the change).

Comment: I already compared the pom.xml from a demo app. No differences that would suggest otherwise.

Comment: You can perhaps add more details into your question like what's the output when pushing your changes, what changes are not deployed, does the build take place, etc.? (The cause of [the linked issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599959/openshift-after-modifying-code-and-git-push-changes-dont-show) could have been just the `maven-war-plugin` missing in the `pom.xml` or something like that.)

Comment: I had a custom library dependency that was failing during the push. Was not  giving much attention to the push logs.