# OpenShift auto deploy not working

Tags: openshift

I am trying to push changes to remote repository in OpenShift but the deployment is not happening. Application is configured to auto deploy and Keep Deployments is 10. Still after successful push i am only seeing 1 entry in deployment list. I am using NetBeans. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: This could be related to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109140/updating-pom-xml-in-openshift). More information about your app and what's the push output could help identifying the cause of the issue.

Comment: I had a custom library dependency that was not added to the remote repository. Once i added it, push was successful and changes started to reflect.